# How do I fix these requirement conflicts?

Tags: 8, webforms, composer

While updating through composer, I am getting an error from the Webform module. Drupal version 8.9.1 updated. How do I resolve this error?

```
Problem 1
    - drupal/webform_node 5.15.0 requires drupal/webform 5.15.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/webform[5.15.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/webform_node 5.15.0 requires drupal/webform 5.15.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/webform[5.15.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - drupal/webform_node 5.15.0 requires drupal/webform 5.15.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/webform[5.15.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for drupal/webform_node (locked at 5.15.0) -> satisfiable by drupal/webform_node[5.15.0].
```

Answer (score 1):

`drupal/webform 5.15.0` seems to be locked below the `v5.15.0` and thus blocking the `drupal\webform_node` update.

- check if you have an explicit version number in your `composer.json` that conflicts with the desired version
- On several occasions, I unblocked such situation by removing the `docroot/vendor` directory followed by a `composer install` command (and removing the `composer.lock` file if a new conflict arised)

`composer.json` is a list of modules with version constraints that is user-defined.
`composer.lock` is the list of currently installed modules generated by `composer install`. If `composer.lock` is present, the list of resolved dependencies will be installed if you do `composer install`. This allow to define and deploy a set of resolved dependencies. `composer update` will resolve the dependencies again and update `composer.lock` (thus the update). From my experience, it could happen that you have unresolved conflict between explicit version definition in `composer.json` and the `composer.lock`. So you could get rid of it, and also the whole vendor directory, and do a composer install from scratch again. If the installation fails again, it must be from a human-generated `composer.json` conflict.

Answer (score 1):

This conflict has beeen resolved using the following command.

```
composer update --with-dependencies
```

Comment: How did you update before that?